# Estimates for linear elliptic PDE in the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

I am struggling to track down any literature on the topic of elliptic regularity when the domain in question is the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the Sobolev spaces $\dot W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, defined to be the completion of $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with respect to the norm $$\lVert \nabla \cdot \rVert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)},$$ and an equation of the form $$\mathrm{div} (A\nabla u) = \mathrm{div} G + f,\quad\text{ in }\mathbb{R}^n $$
where $A$ is symmetric, bounded, and uniformly positive definite (and, say, smooth, even). Then, supposing $1<p<m$: if $G\in L^{\frac{np}{n-p}}(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, I suspect that *a priori* estimates like the following are known $$\lVert \nabla u\rVert_{L^{\frac{np}{n-p}}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq C\lVert G \rVert_{L^{\frac{np}{n-p}}(\mathbb{R}^n)} +C \lVert f\rVert_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$$

Probably there also needs to be some decay assumptions on $A$ as well.

Does anyone know any references for these sorts of things (in fact, I've even struggled finding literature on the topic of the Poisson equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$)?

Comment: Volpert, V. _Elliptic Partial Differential Equations,  Volume 1: Fredholm Theory of Elliptic Problems in Unbounded Domains_ (Springer, 2011), maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The estimate you are asking for is true, provided that the $A(x)$ matrix is uniformly continuous. It is usually called a Calderon-Zygmund estimate, and it is a perturbative estimates (at least when $np/(n-p)$ is far from $2$). The reason it is true is because, if the $A(x)$ is continuous, it is close to a constant matrix in small balls, and this allows you to perturb off the constant-coefficient equation (with zero RHS). The size of the ball you need to take depends on the modulus of continuity of $A(x)$. It is therefore naturally a local estimate. That the estimate is true in the whole space is just because you can consider a (Vitali) covering of the whole space with small balls (if the coefficients are uniformly continuous, then these balls are the same size), apply the local estimate in each ball, and then sum over the balls to recover the estimate in the whole space. But the estimate is really a local estimate.

Comment: When I’ve seen local estimates it’s been with eg $\nabla u\in L^p$ and $f\in L^p$. To get the exponents I mention above, does this follow from applying a Sobolev embedding in the form $\|\nabla u\|_{np/n-p}\leq \|\nabla^2 u\|_p\leq \|f\|_p$?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say: in the statement above, you can without loss of generality assume $f=0$. This is because any $f$ can be written as $div G$ with the integrability as above by CZ estimates for Laplacian and Sobolev embedding. You find $G$ by taking for instance $G=\nabla \Delta^{-1} f$.

Comment: A proof of the CZ estimates with divergence form RHS and continuous diffusion matrix can be found for instance in Prop 7.3 (page 260) of this book: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.05300.pdf